# Category products not displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have an issue with Magento 1.9.I have created Simple Products programmatically and it's displaying in the backend, I have configured all necessary options, but not displaying in the categories.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already mentioned that you have configured all necessary options, I am skipping those steps.

Sometimes it requires reindexing if the products are not showing in the frontend categories.

Please check whether a product is being displayed by its URL or not.

For example, your product ID is 5, then try to hit below URL:

> [yourwebsitebaseurl]/catalog/product/view/id/5

if above works fine, then you only need to do reindexing.

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response @mohit.I have tried by clearing cache & reindexing & renaming var folder.No luck.

Comment: Which options have you configured till now?

Comment: All mandatory options were filled like name ske qty inventory category category search enabled.Product is visible in view page.If I hit with the URL

Comment: Have you caled a product url direkt and you can see the product?

Comment: Yes.Actually initially the product is showing in the category page.I'm facing issue after clearing all the products, customers, categories.After that I have added a new category & then new product in that category,then I'm not able to see.

Comment: So it works now or what do you mean?

Comment: @anil, can you update your question to provide more details?

Comment: The problem occurs due to a third party extension.Now the problem is resolved thanks for ur suggestions.